# Not able to fetch all files from Pentaho

Tags: pentaho-spoon

I have to fetch approximately 2000 files using Pentaho Spoon but I am only getting 175 files.
Is there any way to fetch all the files?

[Pentaho Spoon Failed Fetching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPeSx.png)

Comment: I do not know of a file size limit in fetch files. Please check your file names and regular expression. Do this for each `Get SFPT entry`, starting by the ones which filed (with a red crossed circle).

Comment: The problem is not with the file names nor the regular expressions. And I am doing this with  "Get files with SFTP". If I were only have 10 files, then it works fine. I discovered that the problem is when there are a lot of files and the job is not able to fetch every file.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch 2.000 files at once? How many parallel connections does your client, does the server allow?

Comment: No, Only one connection. I am selecting an entire folder.